# Entity Framework -- reference navigation property how to set just the primary key

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am receiving a JSON object from an API that maps to a POCO class which has a reference navigation property:

```
class Customer 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // .... other properties....
}

class Organization  
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; } 
    // ... other properties...
}
```

My API controller looks like this:

```
public Task<Customer> Post(Customer customer)
```

The API receives some json like this:

```
{ Id: 1, OrganizationId: 5, Name: "Customer name" ...etc... }
```

The `Customer` object doesn't have a property `OrganizationId`, so how can I make sure that the `Customer`'s reference navigation property to the corresponding `Organization` is correct?

Using ASP.NET Core 6.

Comment: @marc_sthanks. If you convert to an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Customer object doesn't have a property OrganizationId*

That's exactly what's missing; if you want to be able to set the foreign key relation by just the `Id`, you need that foreign key column in your class.

Add

```
public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
```

to your `Customer` class, and decorate it with the `[ForeignKey]` data annotation (or define its purpose in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` in FluentAPI), and then set just that value when importing the data.